# Как добавить картинку на JFrame(на задний фон),а потом поместить на фон JLabel?

Tags: java

Как добавить картинку на JFrame(на задний фон),а потом поместить на фон JLabel?

Answer (score 6):

Например так

```
class App extends JFrame {
    private JLabel label;

    public App() {
        setTitle("Example");
        setSize(400, 400);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        setContentPane(new JLabel(new ImageIcon("image.jpg")));

        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        label = new JLabel("Test");
        add(label);

        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        new App();
    }
}
```